# Path to App own directory in External Storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

In a library, I want to return a file that represents App own directory in External Storage, the directory that is returned by this method:

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

But using this method before  API Level 19, needs `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and I do not want to force user to use this permission, specially my method only want to return abstract File and does not want to create directory.

I can use this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getCanonicalPath() + "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files";
```

But I think hard coding is not safe.Is there a way to return that directory without forcing user to use `WRITE` permission?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the hard coded string, you could try to use reflect.

```
    Class<?> environmentClass = Environment.class;
    try {
        Field androidDirectoryField = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            androidDirectoryField = environmentClass.getDeclaredField("DIR_ANDROID");
        } else {
            androidDirectoryField = environmentClass.getDeclaredField("DIRECTORY_ANDROID");
        }
        androidDirectoryField.setAccessible(true);
        final String externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst("data", androidDirectoryField.get(null).toString());

        Log.d(TAG, "external directory " + externalDir);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This method use a declared field `DIRECTORY_ANDROID`, which is a hidden api, don't know if it will change in the future.

Comment: Yes it is not guaranteed that this will not change later.Also `Field androidDirectoryField = environmentClass
       .getDeclaredField("DIRECTORY_ANDROID");` throws `NoSuchFieldException`

Comment: In the lasted version, it changed to `DIR_ANDROID`, take a look at [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r4/core/java/android/os/Environment.java), these are the hidden APIs.